# How to query an Entity based on its descendant properties in App Engine Datastore using Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to find all parent keys from  MessageIndex that meet a criteria.
Note that Message is Parent of MessageIndex.

If I do not specify the immediate ancestor it returns empty all the time.

```
Query query1 = new Query("MessageIndex");
query1.setKeysOnly();
query1.addFilter("receivers", FilterOperator.EQUAL, me);
PreparedQuery pq2 = datastore.prepare(query1);

Iterable<Entity> entities = pq2.asIterable();
HashSet<Key> keys = new HashSet<Key>();
    for (Entity en : entities)
      keys.add(en.getParent());


Map<Key,Entity> messages = datastore.get(keys);
```

I will appreciate any help.